# Do the Gw'oth know that the galaxy is exploding?

Tags: larry-niven, known-space

In the **** of Worlds* Known Space books by Lerner and Niven a species called the Gw'oth is introduced.  They interact with humans and Puppeteers in the novels and eventually establish their own colony planet.  Both humans and Puppeteers learned from Beowulf Shaeffer's core expedition in "At the Core" that the center of the Milky Way galaxy is experiencing a chain reaction of supernovae.  A flood of hard radiation and energetic particles will sleet through Known Space and the galaxy's spiral arms in twenty thousand years.  Upon hearing the news the Puppeteers took their planets and ran, fleeing the galaxy at a significant fraction of lightspeed.  Humans in Known Space apparently think tens of thousands of years is plenty of time to figure out what they should do when the time comes.  But I don't remember anyone ever telling the Gw'oth about the upcoming calamity.

Before I embark on rereading fifteen hundred pages of twisty plot and intrigue I thought I would ask here:

**Do the Gw'oth know that the galaxy is exploding?**

Comment: I knew I forgot to do something. Right there between "turn off the stove" and "check the faucets": "Tell the Gw'oth the galaxy is exploding."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gw'oth probably do find out about the core explosion.

> When Olt'o'ro began to secretly rule the Puppeteers disguised as the Minister of Science, it would have had access to all of the Puppeteer's records (that the various Hindmosts could not delete first) so they would learn about the wave of deadly radiation from those records.

Answer (score 0):

The flight from the core explosion was public knowledge among the Citizens well before the Colonist Revolution - it's mentioned as triggering a "Concordance" change of government - so the Colonists would have known about it too. They'd have noticed the changed acceleration in their tide gauges, if nothing else, but I think it was explicitly in Nessus's design of the "scouting programme".

So I think it's pretty unlikely that the Gw'oth on board ... I've forgotten the ship's name ... would have not found out about it, most likely by being directly told in Sigmund and Alice's explanation of the whys and wherefores of the Pak fleet.

Sigmund still had his memory of the Pak from ARM files, as well as Alice's memories. So ... even if the Puppeteers wanted to keep it secret, they'd have failed, repeatedly. Not a good move with the Gw'oth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve this answer with some direct quotes, or at least specific references to the books where the events you cite are described.